# Rank and edit a field with the ranking number in QGIS attribute table

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, expression

I want to fullfill the field HZ (using field calculator) with a rank number in wich several objects will have the same HZ number. Each time the previous fields are all equal, those objects should be grouped with the same rank number.
the rank is derived from the following order (check the table)

if the **POTENTIAL1** is all equal than i want it to evaluate the **POTENTIAL2**, if its not i want it to group the objects with next HZ rank.

in **bold** are the field while changing automatically "creates" a new **HZ** rank

each time we encounter the word "man" on the field **NAME** it will be in the end of the rank, but just if it is on the same POTENTIAL1

POTENTIAL 1> NAME > POTENTIAL2 > DEEPNESS > STONINESS

| NAME | POTENTIAL1 | POTENTIAL2 | DEEPNESS | STONINESS | HZ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| women and child | 1 | 1 + 1 | 20 + 30 | 35% + 50% | 1 |
| women and child | 1 | **1 linked 2** | 20 + 30 | 35% + 50% | 2 |
| women and child | 1 | **1 + 2** | 20 + 30 | 35% + 50% | 3 |
| women and child | 1 | **2 + 3** | 20 + 30 | 35% + 50% | 4 |
| women and child | **2** | 3 linked 2 | 20 + 30 | 35% + 50% | 5 |
| women and child | 2 | **3 + 4** | 20 + 30 | 50% assoc 50% | 6 |
| women and child | **3** | 2+1 | 20 + 30 | 50% assoc 50% | 7 |
| women and child | **4** | 2+1 | 20 + 30 | 50% assoc 50% | 8 |
| women and child | 4 | 2+1 | 20 + 30 | 50% assoc 50% | 8 |
| women and child | 4 | 2+1 | 20 + 30 | 50% assoc 50% | 8 |
| women and child | 4 | 2+1 | 20 + 30 | **50% assoc 25%** | 9 |
| women and child | 4 | 2+1 | 20 + 30 | 50% assoc 25% | 9 |
| women and child | 4 | 2+1 | **60 + 30** | 75% assoc 50% | 10 |
| women and child | 4 | 2+1 | 60 + 30 | **50% assoc 50%** | 11 |
| women and child | **5** | 2+1 | 60 + 30 | 50% assoc 50% | 12 |
| women and child | 5 | 2+1 | 60 + 30 | 50% assoc 50% | 12 |
| women and child | 5 | 2+1 | **80 + 60** | 50% assoc 50% | 13 |
| women and child | **6** | 2+1 | 60 + 30 | 50% assoc 50% | 14 |
| women and child | 6 | 2+1 | 60 + 30 | 50% assoc 50% | 14 |
| women and child | 6 | 2+1 | 60 + 30 | 50% assoc 50% | 14 |
| **"women,child & man"** | 6 | 2+1 | 60 + 30 | 50% assoc 50% | 15 |
| women and child | **7** | 2+1 | 60 + 30 | 50% assoc 50% | 16 |
| women and child | 7 | 2+1 | **60 + 90** | 50% assoc 50% | 17 |
| women and child | 7 | 2+1 | 60 + 90 | **30% assoc 50%** | 18 |
| **"women,child & man"** | 7 | 2+1 | 60 + 90 | 30% assoc 50% | 19 |
| "women,child & man" | 7 | **2+2** | 60 + 90 | 30% assoc 50% | 20 |
| "women,child & man" | 7 | 2+2 | **60 + 100** | 30% assoc 50% | 21 |
| "women,child & man" | 7 | 2+2 | 60 + 100 | **20% assoc 40%** | 22 |
| "women,child & man" | **8** | 2+1 | 60 + 90 | 30% assoc 50% | 23 |

Notes and Examples:
**POTENTIAL2** , **STONINESS** and **DEEPNESS** are text fields. When composed with **'+'** it means that the composed mean is 50% for the first value and 50% for the second one, while composed with **'linked'** it is 70% for the first value and 30% for the second.

3 Examples:

1 - POTENTIAL2 of 1 linked 2 values less than 1 + 2
2 - DEEPNESS of 20 + 30 values less than 20 linked 30
while
3 - STONINESS 35% + 50% values less than 35% linked 50% ( because the greater the mean of this calculation, the lesser i want it to be grouped in the HZ rank)

Comment: @Babel i did my best, do i still have to reformulate it?

Comment: @Babel i understand, but since i go to different datasets it doesn't returns the correct rank. at least it is grouping well and gives the same rank level for the objects that have all fields equal. i want PONTENTIAL1 and POTENTIAL2 sorted and grouped on ascending, but POTENTIAL2 is a text where 0 linked 1 < 1 linked 0 < 1 + 0 < 1 + 1 < 1 linked 2 < 2 + 1 < 2 linked 1.

the same with DEEPNESS

5 linked 10 < 10 + 5 < 10 linked 5 < 10 linked 20 < 20 + 10 < 20 linked 10 < 20 + 20 .....

Comment: different with STONINESS:

'75% + 60%' <  '60% + 75%' < '60% linked 75%' < '20% linked 30%' < '10% + 25%' < '20%' < '5% + 10%'<  '5% linked 10%' <' 5%'

if all the previous fields are equal the lesses the  STONINESS, the bigger the rank.

and of course if the "POTENTIAL1" is the same, but there appears the word 'man' in the text of "NAME" those objects pass automatically for the end of the ranking, and i will rank those separetelly in ghe end, looking for POTENTIAL2, DEEPNESS and STONINESS again. wich means that they might appear with higher rank even if POTENTIAL2 is lesser

Comment: OK, so you have complex conditions and you should create a classification for each field. As a workaround, you could create a new integer field with a classification for `Potential1`, another for `Potential2` etc. From your explanantion, I still don't get the very logic that applies for each field and so, it's difficult to help. Can you clearly state (not in the comments! Include all relevant information in your initial question by editing it): 1) the order in whicht the fields should be considered for the final rank, 2) the detailed criteria to order the content of each field.

Comment: Please add a table with test data and all the cases that could appear, including the final output you want to get. Like this, it's easier to test. Probably, if things get too complicated, it's better to post a separate question for each field, how to create the correct order, based on your field values. You can then use this together with my solution below to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use this expression (explanation see below):

```
array_find (
    array_distinct( 
        array_agg(
            POTENTIAL1  || NAME  ||  POTENTIAL2  ||  DEEPNESS  ||  STONINESS
        )
    ),
    POTENTIAL1  || NAME  ||  POTENTIAL2  ||  DEEPNESS  ||  STONINESS
)+1
```

*Field `cat` created with the expression:*
[image]

*You can add additional conditions to this basic expression as to how exactly you want to sort the values in the fields. However, your question is too confusing to give concrete advice, try explaining it in easier understandable words. Key to solve the issue is to create an additional, separate classification for each field in an integer format. This makes it much easier to create all kind of sort orders.*

Explanation:

- Use [`array_agg()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-agg) to generate an array that contains an element for each feature  (row) in your table. The element consists of a concatenation ([pipes operator `||` to concatenate](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#expression-function-operators-concat)) of the fields you mentioned.
- As your test data has 29 features, this array contains 29 elements, some of them duplicates like for rows 8, 9 and 10 as here, all values are the same. To get rid of duplicates,use [`array_distinct()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-distinct).
- Now use [`array_find()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-find) to check for each feature (row) separately which of the element (index) in the array is equal to the concatenated text string for the current feaure.
- As array indices start with 0 (first element = 0, second element = 1 etc.), add 1: `+1`.